# cast object to abstract class and interface at the same time

Tags: c#, casting

I'm trying to make a game in C#.
First see some of my code so far:

**My abstract class gridobject**

It contains all general properties of my gridobjects (wall, player, enemy, etc)

```
abstract class GridObject
{
    public Rectangle Rect;

    ...
    //all kind of getters and setters for location and size: X, Y, Height, Width
    ...
}
```

**Interface Moving**

This interface contains the properties for a moving gridobject:

```
interface Moving
{
    int Xspeed { get; set; }
    int Yspeed { get; set; }
    void Move();
}
```

Now I want to add gravity to my game:

```
public void doGravity(GridObject obj)
    {
        //check if intersects && if object isn't the same as the given object.
        while (AllGridObjects.FindAll(item => item.Rect.IntersectsWith(obj.Rect) && item != obj).Count > 0)
        {
            obj.Y += obj.Yspeed;
            obj.Yspeed++;
        }
    }
```

This gives a compilation error ofcourse. Because Yspeed isn't a required field in abstract class  GridObject.
Maybe the title isn't correct and maybe also my question, but how can I cast an object to an abstract class and an interface to make sure that propertie Y and propertie Yspeed is required?
What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Create one more local variable of type `Moving`? Note: .net convention uses `I` prefix for interfaces, It should be `IMoving` rather than `Moving`.

Comment: Will my code still run fast enough if I use two variables? And thanks for the tip!

Comment: Of course, try it out. Make sure you're not doing a cast inside the loop. Let the `IMoving` local be outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DLeh I found the solution.
I am using an extra abstract class `MovingGridObject` that inherits from `GridObject` and `Moving`.
That is the type I am going to use in my `doGravity` method.

Answer (score 1):

Cast / convert it to the type you need before you set the value.

```
if(obj is Moving)
{
    var objectAsMoving = obj as Moving; //or (Moving)obj;
    objectAsMoving.Y += objectAsMoving.Yspeed;
    objectAsMoving.Yspeed++;
}
```

Comment: When I do it like this, My program gives an compilation error for objectAsMoving.Y since it is a property of gridobject.

Comment: you need to set up some way to convert between these objects, if you need to do so. Create a class that inherits from `GameObject` and `Moving` and call it `MoveableGameObject` or something, then cast to that from `GameObject` instead.

Comment: Thank you!! that is the solution I have been looking for

Comment: you're welcome. don't forget to mark the question the answer by clicking the check mark if this answered your question. Welcome to StackOverflow!